# Change type of multiple columns from datetime to date simultaneously (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have multiple columns in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and I want to transform all of them to `yyyy-mm-dd` format with a single (preferably vectorized) line of code.

In R, I would do something along the lines of:

```
df[, c("col1", "col2") := list(col1 = as.Date(col1), col2 = as.Date(col2))]
```

I want to avoid doing this individually for every column. So far I can only think of the following trivial solution:

```py
df["col1"] = df["col1"].dt.date
df["col2"] = df["col2"].dt.date
```

So I have two questions: how do you operate on multiple columns in a single line of code and how do you turn `datetime` objects to `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.choice(pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31", freq="2H").strftime('Y%-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), size=5),
    'b': np.random.choice(pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31", freq="2H").strftime('Y%-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), size=5),
    'c': np.random.choice(pd.date_range("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31", freq="2H").strftime('Y%-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), size=5)
})

df.loc[:, 'a':'c'] = df.loc[:, 'a':'c'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.date)
```

```
    a           b           c 
0   2019-04-19  2019-08-11  2019-11-01
1   2019-04-02  2019-07-04  2019-08-29
2   2019-03-02  2019-06-02  2019-11-25
3   2019-08-22  2019-04-27  2019-04-28
4   2019-05-10  2019-09-21  2019-12-07
```

Comment: Would it also work if you passin the columns within a list? For example `df.loc[:, ["a","b","c"]].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.date)`

Comment: @ArturoSbr yes, it would. Just tested

Answer (score 2):

You may use `select_dtypes` to select only `datetime` dtype columns and `stack`, convert to `dt.date` and `unstack` and update back to df

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes('datetime').stack().dt.date.unstack())
```